# How to insert javascript to enable MathJax on GitHub wiki pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mathjax, dotjs

The GitHub wiki pages no longer support [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). It seems like the [dotjs Chrome extension](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs) might be a way to enable MathJax on these pages.

Here is my first attempt at creating javascript that would execute on github.com pages, and insert the right code needed to enable MathJax:

```
[~]$ cat .js/github.com.js
(function () {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
 })();
```

This doesn't work, however, and the following error appears in the Chrome JavaScript Console:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
https://github.com https://a248.e.akamai.net https://jobs.github.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://secure.gaug.es https://collector.githubapp.com https://gist.github.com".
    c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML:29
```

What is the correct JavaScript?

Comment: Now you know _why_ GitHub no longer supports MathJax.  MathJax doesn't work with CSP.  https://github.com/blog/1477-content-security-policy

Comment: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/256

Comment: Does this mean that I can't do what I want unless MathJax becomes compatible with CSP?

Comment: @Michael Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the source code of MathJax because it uses the eval function there

Comment: The use of `eval()` and `new Function()` in MathJax were fixed when https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/256 was fixed.